# Is there a WSProxy equivalent of the SQL "SELECT * "?

Tags: marketing-cloud, wsproxy

I am curious if there is a way, specifically in WSProxy, to select all data that is associated with an object without individually identifying each column.

For instance, instead of

```
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var cols = [ "Name", "CustomerKey", "CategoryID", "IsSendable"];
var data = prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols);
```

Is there something like

```
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var cols = [ * ];
var data = prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close -- just add some quotes around the asterisk:

```javascript
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var cols = ['*'];
var data = prox.retrieve("DataExtension", cols);
```

Comment: Just be aware this does not work in every object. Usually its better to do a describe to that object and grab the retrievable fields then use those in your call.